# Travelling to Kuwait from Bangalore

Tags: kuwait

My husband will be travelling to Kuwait on work visa, his done with medical visa stamping and pcc.
I have heard from people that he has to have employment contract as well to show in the immigration? Does he require it or he can directly go for immigration?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have done the visa stamping you can fly. Your husband should still ask his employer about the employment contract. They should issue it when your husband is in Kuwait.

From [this website:](https://welcome2kuwait.wordpress.com/visa-process/)

> My question is what is the next procedure?  I only got an offer
>   letter, not an employment contract. When I can get it? The offer
>   letter was just one page and just the position salary benefit only
>
> Once the stamping is done you can fly. Ask your employer abt the
>   employment contract. Normally they issue when you are in Kuwait.